# best practice for android step by step interface

Tags: android, navigation, wizard

I'm in need of creating quite complicated UI for users to add new records in db. It will be mostly about photos, users have to take several photos of specified types: like id photo, face photo, area photo, etc. I'm confused, what will be the best way to guide user through all required steps? At first there'll be form to input text data like name and birthday, and then each time user should be prompted like "take id photo now", "take face photo now". Steps can be skipped and user can go back and forward across completed/skipped steps.

We can see similar mechanics on device first start when we input accounts and set some basic preferences.

So what will be the best and proper widget to use here? I'm thinking about creating series of alertdialogs, but back_forward nav can be hard task in this case. Maybe there's readymade class or even native control that I'm not aware of.

Comment: System.out.println("Hello World"); is a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what will be the best and proper widget to use here?

I'd consider [Roman Nurik's `WizardPager`](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager), since what you are describing is a wizard.

Comment: Right. Wizard is the word, it was on the tip of tongue. Now I can see a lot of wizard solutions and related topics here in SO. Thank you.